# Is every normal subgroup the kernel of some self-homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

Let $G$ be a group. If there is a homomorphism $f:G\to G$ (special case of the codomain being arbitrary group), then the kernel $f^{-1}(id)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

But now the other way around: Start out with the existence of a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$. Is there necessarily a homomorphism $f:G\to G$ such that the kernel of $f$ is $H$?

Comment: I edited the title to clarify the question. Let me know if you agree with it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde that’s fine thanks!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1826655/necessary-and-sufficient-condition-for-a-normal-group-to-be-kernel-of-a-homomorp

Comment: A more interesting question would be: for which groups is this true? Trivially true for simple groups and also true for finite cyclic groups. Are there any others?

Answer (score 7):

That's false.

If $G=\mathbb{Z}$ then any homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ takes the form $f(a)=ma$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Clearly the kernel is trivial (unless $m=0$ then the kernel is everything). However for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have that $n\mathbb{Z}$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. In particular $2\mathbb{Z}$ is not a kernel of any homomorphim from $\mathbb{Z}$ to itself.

However, it is possible to "correct" this statement. If you only request an homomorphism from $G$ to some other group. Given any normal subgroup $H$, the quotient homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow G/H$ which sends $g\mapsto g+H$ has $H$ as it's kernel. In other words, every normal subgroup is a kernel of some homomorphism, **not necessarily from $G$ to itself**.